# Как в AutoCompleteTextView сделать запись прозрачной?

Tags: android

Как можно в AutoCompleteTextView сделать запись прозрачной (типа поиск) ?

Comment: фон ему выставьте нужный

Comment: Вам нужен какой-то hint (некое слово-подсказка серым цветом, обозначающее действие в виджете) ?

Comment: @pavlofff, я тоже так подумал, но hint же не отображается, когда текст воодишь...

Comment: Вам что нужно опрозрачить? Выпадающий список или сам edittext?